# Execution time zero for non-trivial code golang

Tags: go, time

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

func main() {
    time1 := time.Now()
    f := 0
    g := 0
    h := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        f += 1
        g += f*2 + (f*f) + (f*f*f*f*f)
        h += g*g*g + f*f
    }
    time2 := time.Now()
    second2 := time2.Sub(time1)
    fmt.Println(second2.Nanoseconds())
}
```

This is printing `0` as output. I also added some print statements to add IO time, then also `0` was the output.
Can someone explain why this is so?
Link: https://play.golang.org/p/GUy9geJXBUA

Comment: What is the resolution of `time.Now()`? Does `Nanoseconds()` contain just nanosecond fractional part of the difference, or the entire difference expressed in nanosecond units?

Comment: Unrelated but you can use `time.Since(time1)` to save creating the second time.

Comment: @jurez it contains entire difference expressed in nanosecond units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're running on the Go playground, where `time.Now()` is frozen and always returns the time of the Go release announcement. (You can do `fmt.Println(time.Now())` to check.)

Comment: To add to this, you can add a `time.Sleep(time.Second)` and you get your expected outcome.

Comment: @JimWright Yes, it works. Now, I am wondering how does `time.Sleep` works and for other things, `time.Now()` is frozen(in terms of code).

Comment: That's probably just how the playground works. Do you get the same result locally?

Comment: no, I meant how does the playground implements this behaviour :p. Nvm, will check

Comment: @AbhayPratapSingh `time.Now()` is [not frozen in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k7mqq8LhGol). You can read how the Go team emulated this [here](https://blog.golang.org/playground) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/JBsCrDEVyVE/m/30MaQsiQcWoJ).